# eregi() deprecated - I am not sure how to rewrite this code

Tags: php

Deprecated code:

```
function validate_email($email)
{
    return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);
}
```

I am a JavaScript beginner. The above code gives an error.  I am not too sure how to rewrite using preg_match.

Comment: Make sure you add regex delimiters with `preg_match` and it should work. But also `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
function validate_email($email)
{
    return (1 === preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email));
}
```

preg_match() should be used rather than eregi. You must include the slashes at the begining and end of the pattern. And finally, the "/i" at the end of the pattern makes it case-insensitive.